# scrapy LinkExtractor doesn't extract correct url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using Scrapy to crawl a website. my start_url is a search results with many pages. When I use LinkExtractor, it will add some more to the url I want. so I can only crawl the start_url, and all other polluted urls will get 404.

```
2015-12-15 20:38:43 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-12-15 20:38:43 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped     0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-12-15 20:38:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-12-15 20:38:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> (referer: None)
2015-12-15 20:38:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p2.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93++++++++++++++++> (referer: http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93)
2015-12-15 20:38:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <404 http://task.zhubajie.com/success/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p2.htmlkw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93++++++++++++++++>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
...
2015-12-15 20:39:18 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-12-15 20:39:18 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2578,
 'downloader/request_count': 6,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 6,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 57627,
 'downloader/response_count': 6,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 5,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 15, 12, 39, 18, 70000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 12,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 15, 12, 38, 43, 693000)}
2015-12-15 20:39:18 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I want get

```
http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p2.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93
```

other than:

```
http://task.zhubajie.com/success/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p2.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93++++++++++++++++".
```

I don't know what cause this. Anyone can help me?

```
start_urls = [
    'http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93',
]

rules = [
    #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'task.zhubajie.com/success/p\d+\.html',), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
]
```

EDIT:
I tried to use process_value like this.

```
 Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]'),     process_value=lambda x: x.strip()), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
```

and this:

```
    def process_0(value):
      m = re.search('http://task.zhubajie.com/success/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20', value)
      if m:
        return m.strip('http://task.zhubajie.com/success/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20')
```

They don't work, neither. Both of them have the same log,and visit the wrong url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the links in the paginator have a lot of whitespaces http://screencloud.net/v/qQLW. You should be able to preprocess scrapped values before getting a result with the following code:

```
# coding: utf-8
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


def process_value(v):
    v1 = v.split()[-1]
    if v1.startswith('http'):
        v = v1
    return v


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spider'
    start_urls = [
        'http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93'
    ]
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]'),
                           process_value=process_value), follow=True)
    ]
```

Spider output:

```
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-12-18 10:35:37 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-12-18 10:35:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> (referer: None)
2015-12-18 10:35:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p4.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> (referer: http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93)
2015-12-18 10:35:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p6.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> (referer: http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93)
2015-12-18 10:35:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p3.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2015-12-18 10:35:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p3.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> (referer: http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93)
2015-12-18 10:35:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> (referer: http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93)
2015-12-18 10:35:47 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p5.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> (referer: http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93)
2015-12-18 10:35:54 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://task.zhubajie.com/success/p2.html?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93> (referer: http://task.zhubajie.com/success/?kw=%E7%99%BE%E5%BA%A6%E7%9F%A5%E9%81%93)
2015-12-18 10:35:54 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-12-18 10:35:54 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2380,
 'downloader/request_count': 7,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 7,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 196525,
 'downloader/response_count': 7,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 7,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 36,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 18, 7, 35, 54, 945271),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 7,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 7,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 7,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 7,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 7,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 18, 7, 35, 37, 907281)}
2015-12-18 10:35:54 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

[`LinkExtractor` docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)

Comment: I tried this, but it did't work. Also, I tried make process_value = x.strip("http://task.zhubajie.com/success/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"). It did't work neither.

Comment: update your code with what you tried and the new logs

Comment: I've updated the answer too. Please try `process_value(v)` instead of `lambda x: x.strip()`.

Comment: Failed again. It seems that when I want to visit the url with specific keyword, the system will first visit the main page 'http://task,zhubajie,com/success/...', then move to the url I want  adding keyword. It doesn't visit directly.

Comment: Please have a look at the source code of my spider. I hope it will help.

Comment: It worked! @twil Very Thank you for your patient. The function process_value should not in the Spider Class, and do not need ' '. Thank you again. This is my first time to ask a question in Stackoverflow. I enjoy it.